# random forest validation error vs training error

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

You’ve built a random forest model with 10000 trees. You got delighted after
getting training error as 0.00. But, the validation error is 34.23. What is going
on?

Answer (score 1):

That means you're overfitting your model such that it gives no training error, but unable to generalize correctly to OOB.

One possibility is that you have very complicated trees in your model (e.g. no pruning). Another possibility is that you have a "cheating" feature in your data set (and that's also your only feature), for example, Case ID.